# Comparing FFprobe to Wave Agent Beta

Tags: ffmpeg, timecode

Wav Agent outputs the following when I drag the same file in, so the data has to be in the file somewhere, and I just don't know how to look for it:

> ```
> WavAgent: StartTC: 13:09:21:18
> ```

Now, FFmpeg with the following arguments creates the following :

```
ffprobe -i "_Audio Test_CRO_01.wav" -print_format json -show_streams -show_format

ffprobe version 3.4.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Copyright (c) 2007-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.18.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
{
Input #0, wav, from '_Audio Test_CRO_01.wav':
  Metadata:
    encoded_by      : Pro Tools
    originator_reference: JTFyPBDM2GpaaaGk
    date            : 2018-02-01
    creation_time   : 13:28:24
    time_reference  : 2273356800
  Duration: 00:00:48.22, bitrate: 1197 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s24le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 48000 Hz, 1 channels, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s
    "streams": [
        {
            "index": 0,
            "codec_name": "pcm_s24le",
            "codec_long_name": "PCM signed 24-bit little-endian",
            "codec_type": "audio",
            "codec_time_base": "1/48000",
            "codec_tag_string": "[1][0][0][0]",
            "codec_tag": "0x0001",
            "sample_fmt": "s32",
            "sample_rate": "48000",
            "channels": 1,
            "bits_per_sample": 24,
            "r_frame_rate": "0/0",
            "avg_frame_rate": "0/0",
            "time_base": "1/48000",
            "duration_ts": 2314530,
            "duration": "48.219375",
            "bit_rate": "1152000",
            "bits_per_raw_sample": "24",
            "disposition": {
                "default": 0,
                "dub": 0,
                "original": 0,
                "comment": 0,
                "lyrics": 0,
                "karaoke": 0,
                "forced": 0,
                "hearing_impaired": 0,
                "visual_impaired": 0,
                "clean_effects": 0,
                "attached_pic": 0,
                "timed_thumbnails": 0
            }
        }
    ],
    "format": {
        "filename": "_Audio Test_CRO_01.wav",
        "nb_streams": 1,
        "nb_programs": 0,
        "format_name": "wav",
        "format_long_name": "WAV / WAVE (Waveform Audio)",
        "duration": "48.219375",
        "size": "7215254",
        "bit_rate": "1197071",
        "probe_score": 99,
        "tags": {
            "encoded_by": "Pro Tools",
            "originator_reference": "JTFyPBDM2GpaaaGk",
            "date": "2018-02-01",
            "creation_time": "13:28:24",
            "time_reference": "2273356800"
        }
    }
}
```

Is `time_reference` a clue? I have calculated that from Jan 1 1970, but that's not accurate. I'd like to know how I can get the start frame of timecode from this WAV file.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I figured it out "time_reference": "2273356800" isn't epoch time, it's samples since midnight. So that worked out at 48khz to 13:09:21:18 
time_reference is a really horrible way of labeling that :O
Also this is assuming 30 fps, so I'll have to look and see where I can grab that from. Maybe there's more metadata to dig through.... ugh...